# where is the android.permission.INTERNET permission check point in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

Most of the permission checking will happened in checkPermission or checkUidPermission in current Android permission framework. 
But the android.permission.INTERNET permission will not be checked in these two methods. So I wondering about the exactly checking function/method of this permission in Android.

Comment: This is more of a platform question than developer question, just write an app that uses internet access and use the debugger to stop on a SecurityException being thrown. That will give you the file and line, then you can check the code in the [AOSP repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the code.

The system permission like INTERNET or file operations will be controlled by gids with the user id. The uid without the net gid will not be able to create the socket and will return EACCES(permission denied) by linux kernel.